# What is the best width router bit for cutting ply?

Tags: routers

I will be using a 1.4KW router that has ¼ inches, 6mm and 8mm collets, and cutting ply using curved templates.    I do not care what the width of the bit is, as I can make my template to match the bit.

A wider bit is stronger; however a wider bit also has to remove more wood, what is the best compromise on bit width?

Answer (score 2):

Rough out the cut with a jig saw (or band saw), followed by a router with a small-diameter large-shank bit for a smooth finish.

Comment: I don't have a jig saw or a band saw, just a circular as well as some hand saws.

Comment: how thick is the plywood? how many linear feet of cutting are entailed, per piece & per project?

Comment: The ply will be 18mm (2/3”), there will be about 30cm (1 foot) of cutting per piece and I need to make 6 identical pieces.    I don’t mind having to do many passes to cut each piece.   (I also have lots of fire doors to hang, hence going for a 1/4 inch router.)

Comment: A 1/4" router ought to be fine for 200cm of 18mm plywood.  I'd use whatever bits I have laying around, opting for, say, a small carbide bit. My jig saws have never seen much use, but have been quite handy in certain situations.  If you already have some cordless tools, you might be able to find a good price on a cordless jigsaw sold without a battery or charger, or a rebuilt corded jig saw.  It'd go a long way on a project like this.